# Regex - Disable specific substrings of the same line

Tags: java, regex

Let's assume that I want to match word "cat", but before this word there shouldn't be word "mouse" on the same line

Matched:

```
Hello, cat!
```

Matched

```
Hello, mouse!
Hello, cat!
```

Not matched

```
Hello, mouse and cat
```

But it should process any lines correctly, for example, just "cat" should be matched too.
I have a regex which doesn't work

```
(?!\bmouse\b)[^\n]*cat
```

May someone help please? Thanks

Comment: What regex flavor/language are you using?

Comment: I guess you might try [`^(?!.*\bmouse\b.*\bcat\b).*`](https://regex101.com/r/hU6kV9/1). However, it will match the whole line. You need an infinite width negative lookbehind to match just `cat` not preceded with a `mouse`. And that depends on what regex library you are using. See [`(?<!\bmouse\b.*)\bcat\b` demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cbmouse%5cb.*)%5cbcat%5cb&i=Hello%2c+mouse!%0d%0aHello%2c+cat!%0d%0aNot+matched%0d%0a%0d%0aHello%2c+mouse+and+cat)

Comment: @anubhava, java.util.regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it won't work, because my engine doesn't allow to use .* with lookbehinds

Comment: In Java, you might try a hackish way of `"(?<!\\bmouse\\b.{0,1000})\\bcat\\b"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, should I put `[^\n]` instead of `.` before quantifier?

Comment: The dot is matching any character but a newline without `Pattern.DOTALL` mode on. `[^\n]` matches any character but a linefeed. I think a dot is more efficient than the negated character class.

Comment: Thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting since my answer in the comments worked for you.

You can use a constrained width lookbehind (one with a limiting quantifier):

```
"(?<!\\bmouse\\b.{0,1000})\\bcat\\b"
```

Since the min and max limits are known, the engine knows possible lookbehind pattern length.

See the [regex demo](http://fiddle.re/pz98ya)

Pattern breakdown:

- `(?<!\\bmouse\\b.{0,1000})` - check if there is a whole word `mouse` before current position separated with 0 to 1000 any characters but a newline
- `\\bcat\\b` - whole word `cat`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex with negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*?\bmouse\b.*\bcat\b).*
```

`(?!.*?\bmouse\b.*\bcat\b)` is negative lookahead to assert failure when `mouse` is present before `cat` in same line. `\b` is used for word boundary assertion.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eT9pT2/2)